# What to put into the dependency array of useEffect if I want to listen to a boundingClientRect() change of an element?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to get an `position:absolute` arrow that is pointing to a `targetelement` to reposition whenever something in my layout changes, if that affects the position of the `targetelement` (e.g. sidebar opens or closes or window gets resized).
Something along the lines of whenever the `boundingClientrect` of the `targetelement` changes. Adding `elemRect.left` etc to the dependency array doesn't work as I intend it to unfortunately. In that case it updates the arrow only once when the state changes, instead of following the animation of the target smoothly.

I've tried a `ResizeObserver` as well which doesn't fire whenever the target element moves but only when it resizes.

Omitting the dependency array (like in the example) achieves what I want to happen but it completely fries the computer. I also frequently get a "Maximum updated depth exceeded error" which makes sense since the arrow updates the state basically all the time.

Using `useLayoutEffect` doesn't work either.

I have a small example of what I need here:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/suspicious-haze-4jdi1

I'd gladly take advice on how to tackle this problem properly.

Thanks in advance!